# Replacing missing data in pandas.DataFrame not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, boolean-logic

I'm digging in the [Kaggle's Titanic excercise](http://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic-gettingStarted).

I have a pandas.DataFrame which column 'Age' has some `NaN'` values scattered and another column called `IsAlone` I created whose values are `1` or `0` depending the person was alone on that ship based on a personal rule.

I'm trying to replace the `NaN` values on column `Age` for people that were alone with the mean age of those who were alone, and the same way with those who weren't alone. The purpose is just exercise pandas DataFrame, replacing `NaN` values based on a rule.

I'm doing this to those who were alone:

```
df_train[(df_train.IsAlone.astype(bool) & df_train.Age.isnull() )].Age = \
    df_train[(df_train.IsAlone.astype(bool) & ~df_train.Age.isnull() )].Age.mean()
```

And the same way to those who weren't alone:

```
df_train[(~df_train.IsAlone.astype(bool) & df_train.Age.isnull() )].Age = \
    df_train[(~df_train.IsAlone.astype(bool) & ~df_train.Age.isnull() )].Age.mean()
```

But this is not working at all, the column `Age` still have the same `NaN` values.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: show example data and expected result.

Comment: try `df_train.loc[ that condition here, 'Age'] = whatever`

Comment: @behzad.nouri That worked fine! Thanks. Would you be so kind as to elaborate a brief answer to get the prize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the values are changed on a *copy* of the original frame. Refer to [Returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) for details. As in the documentation:

> When setting values in a pandas object, care must be taken to avoid what is called *chained indexing*.

To change the values on a *view* of the original frame you may do:

```
j = df_train.IsAlone.astype(bool) & df_train.Age.isnull()
i = df_train.IsAlone.astype(bool) & ~df_train.Age.isnull()
df_train.loc[j, 'Age'] = df_train.loc[i, 'Age'].mean()
```